# JQuery head tag

Tags: jquery, head, zen

I have a fresh install of Joomla 2.5.9 on a test server, the only added extensions are jb_library, Zen Tools and Anycode. I am using a Joomla template Beez 20.

I am using an ECWID shop with a widget that requires me to call jquery.

The only way I could get that widget to work AND have a Zen tools lightbox was to add the jquery paths in the head and add a character of some sort after the Javascript. (Even a full-stop).

Example (The exclamation mark is the extra character in this instance):

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3    /jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js">    </script>!
</head>
```

Now the shop widget and lightbox will both now work at the same time but this extra character will display at the top of all my pages.

With the jquery pahths in the head without that extra character the ECWID shop will not load at all and gives an error message about missing body tags. If I add the jquery paths in the body instead the ECWID widget works but zen tools lightbox does not.

I am very much a newbie to this sort of coding, can anyone suggest a way I can either stop having to use the extra character in the head or stop it displaying on my pages?

URL:

```
http://79.170.44.128/test-13.co.uk/
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: put your script.js at bottom of body tag it will be working fine

Comment: Thanks for replying Rajesh. That also gives the ECWID missing body tags error.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, really strange. Basically, this is done like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

No extra mark and anything else...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I do that then the ECWID shop will not load at all and gives an error message about missing body tags.

Comment: I also tried adding the two jquery paths as Roasted described but after the closing body tag (Instead of in the head) and got the ECWID missing body tags message. I also tried putting the no conflict line that Abhilasha described between those two jquery paths after the closing body tag and got the same missing body tags error.

Comment: Update, I tried putting my extra character at other places instead. It could go in lots of places in the head, and before the head too. It could even go at the very start of my template before the opening php, but if I did not add it somewhere closing head tag  I got the ECWID missing body tags error and no shop. Zen tools got messed up if I put the extra character anywhere other than after the jquery paths in the head. At all times the extra charcater showed on my pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding jQuery noConflict in between both line and remove exclamation as shown below

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That also gives the missing body tags error

Answer (score 0):

try this one , Put the below code after closing tag of body

```
  </body>
  <script src="//app.ecwid.com/script.js?2158433" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     window.addEvent('load', function() {
            new JCaption('img.caption');
        });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var big ='72%';
     var small='53%';
     var altopen='is open';
     var altclose='is closed';
     var bildauf='/test-13.co.uk/templates/beez_20/images/plus.png';
     var bildzu='/test-13.co.uk/templates/beez_20/images/minus.png';
     var rightopen='Open info';
     var rightclose='Close info';
     var fontSizeTitle='Font size';
     var bigger='Bigger';
     var reset='Reset';
     var smaller='Smaller';
     var biggerTitle='Increase size';
     var resetTitle='Revert styles to default';
     var smallerTitle='Decrease size';
  </script>
```

Comment: Hi again Rajesh, that gave the same missing body tags error...thanks for having another go

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the ! from the code. There is no reason for it to be there.
Anything not between tags will just output on your page as html. 
Why did you add the ! in the firstplace?

Comment: Also, tell jblibrary to use jquery noconflict and consider telling  it to remove mootools if you are not using it.

Comment: Why I came to add the ! in the first place was a newbie route and not logical. I have tried jb_library using no conflict, and also tried telling it to remove mootools, result was the ECWID missing body tags error (If I did not use the additional character).

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

Joomlabamboo tried a new alpha version of Zen Tools that worked! I will post here when the new version is available for download. (My version with bug was the latest available for download at the time JB_mod_zentools_J2.5_J3.0_1.9.6). The developer also wrote that after version 1.9.7 it will be an standalone extension so it is not going to need jb_library.

BTW JB-library is a free extension, Zen Tools is a club extension.

Thanks very much to all for your help, what a great forum
Suzanne

Answer (score 0):

The Zen Tools (Standalone verdsion - no jb_library) update has now been released by Joomlabamboo:

http://www.joomlabamboo.com/blog/joomla-extensions/zentools-update-plus-some-details-about-v2